# Setting Multiple Prefetch Size for Different Topic in The Same Project

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I made 2 ActiveMQ consumer with different topic in 1 project. As i read some documentation and many question about setting `prefetch-size`, there are 3 way to setting it : by url, by PrefetchPolicy, and by destination. Can we setting different `prefetch-size` for the consumers in 1 project?

For example :

- 1st topic('foo') consumer `prefetch-size = 100`
- 2nd topic('bar') consumer `prefetch-size = 50`.

Comment: You've already listed the 3 ways this is possible: URL, PrefetchPolicy, and destination. What more do you need? There are examples in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html).

Comment: what i need is can we use 1 project to use 2 consumer with different prefetch limit. im trying setting it and all of it become the 1st one. if 1st one is get 100, the other one that i want to limit 50 become 100.

Comment: Yes, of course you can. Just use any of the 3 options already discussed.